# Identity server 4 add roles to exsiting access token by reference

Tags: c#, identityserver4

How to add new roles to an **existing** access token (by reference) in identity server 4, without generating new a new access token?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot add `role` to an already issued token. `role` comes as a set of `claim` in a token. The value should be provided at the stage of generating the token. It doesn't matter if the type of the token is jwt or reference.

`IClaimProvider` kicks in when `identityserver4` is trying to create a token. The provider is in charge of searching for `claims` on a user when a `subjectId` exists. Presence of `subjectId` may indicate that the grant type involves a `subject` such as `ResourceOwnerPassword`, thus you have to add a role to users if you want the token to have the `role` value.

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "1",
    Username = "alice",
    Password = "alice",
    Claims =
    {
        .
        .
        .
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "myrole") // <-- add a role here
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

The immutability of security token is a fundamental principle to maintain the integrity and security of the authentication process. If it was possible to modify any values in the token after it's issued, `OAuth` didn't even have to come up with the concept of `refresh token`.

Comment: thank you for the great explanation!  What would you suggest if the user has to confirm/approve an agreement upon successful login? This confirmation should add/change user's role.

Comment: I have no clue what kind of suggestion you're looking for. Could you explain the problem you have? If you could update the role before issueing the `access token`, the role claim will be added to the token unless you have a new implementation of `IClaimProvider` that intentionally gets rid of the role claim.